# While scrolling, Need to add new class in jQuery perfect scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery [perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar) to my web application. I have called perfect-scrollbar in ready function like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
    "use strict";
    $('.cs-scroll, .cs-scroll-2').perfectScrollbar();
});
```

How can i add the new class in  perfect-scrollbar?

Can you help me ?

Comment: I mean while scrolling, i need to add new class...

Comment: any one can help me....